# Castle ActiveRecord and The ActiveRecord VS Solution Template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, castle-activerecord

What do you need to do or install to get the The ActiveRecord VS Solution Template working in Visual Studio 2008? I have installed the Castle Project, but I don't see any new solution templates in VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Castle RC3, the MSI installer includes [Visual Studio integration](http://www.castleproject.org/castle/vsintegration.html) for VS2003 and VS2005 only. For VS2008 integration, see [this post](http://tech.wowkhmer.com/post/2008/11/04/Get-Started-Castle-MonoRail-Project-Template-for-VS2008.aspx).

Comment: +1 - thanks for the info. Could you also tell me which files are required in the Bin folder when you deploy an app?

Comment: For ActiveRecord RC3: Castle.Components.Validator, Castle.Core, Iesi.Collections, NHibernate, Castle.DynamicProxy, log4net

Comment: Both links in this answer are dead.